# Problem with terminal after following instructions: '[How to] Connect your Android Ice Cream Sandwich Phone to Ubuntu for File Access'

Tags: command-line, android

After following the instructions my terminal is constantly spewing out

```
alias: command not found
alias android-disconnect=”fusermount -u /media/Galaxy”
alias: command not found
alias android-connect=”mtpfs -user_allow_other /media/Galaxy”
alias: command not found
alias: command not found
alias android-disconnect=”fusermount -u /media/Galaxy”
alias: command not found
alias android-connect=”mtpfs -user_allow_other /media/Galaxy”
alias: command not found
```

endlessly

What to do?

Comment: which link did you followed?

Comment: i followed this link http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access/

Comment: after following it nothing happened.i read in the reply that you should change the o_allow_other for :user_allow_other, so i did

Comment: after that is went all wierd on me. dont exactly know what i did

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be because you copy-pasted the command to echo the alias to your ~/.bashrc file direct from the website, which unfortunately contains HTML/Unicode quotes (`&#8220;` and `&#8221;`) in place of regular ASCII double quotes - the webpage has this warning:

> re-type the quotes in each command after you’ve copied, otherwise the command won’t work

as you have found. You will need to edit your ~/.bashrc and correct the quote marks, after that the errors should go away.